# In Windows, is there a way to launch a local .exe remotely and have the .exe launch into the logged in session?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line

I've written a .bat file to launch an .exe file.

```
start chrome.exe
```

I'm invoking that .bat file from a remote machine using psexec (pstools)

```
psexec 10.60.103.10 -u admin -p pizza1234 "C:\code\myBatFile.bat"
```

When I invoke the .bat file locally, it launches Chrome into the current user session, and I can see it on the desktop. If I invoke the .bat file remotely (as described above), Chrome launches into a different session, and I can't see it on the (remote) desktop.

*Is there a way to force an application to launch into a specific session via the Windows cmd?*

Comment: You may want to check out Powershell.

Comment: Check out the `-i` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys. I've been running the psexece from Powershell, and I tried the -i flag with no luck. Much appreciate the ideas, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a popup like shown below:

[image]

You have to click on the `View the message` to actually see the window, in this case, notepad.

If you want it in a differnt session you have to specify that with the `-i` flag - `-i 1` etc. 0 is the default and is the console session.

Comment: `0` is not the console session anymore; it is the services session starting with Vista.

Answer (score 0):

I use -i and -d switches.

```
psexec \\10.60.103.10 -u admin -p pizza1234 -i -d chrome.exe
```

I assume that chrome.exe is in the path of the destination machine.